Is there a compiler flag which allows a shared library to call a function coming from the shared library which opened it?
Below is a minimal reproducible example, where the goal is to call b_util() from a(). My question is whether it's possible to do this without explicitly passing a b_util() function pointer to a.c.
I am looking for a flag like -rdynamic, as discussed in this Stack Overflow post, which allows a shared library to call functions from the main executable. Compiling a.c or b.c with this flag prints the same runtime error, but maybe there is a way the flag could be utilized?
You can compile and run the below code with gcc c.c -o c.out && gcc b.c -o b.so -shared -fPIC && gcc a.c -o a.so -shared && ./c.out, but the problem is that it prints dlopen: ./a.so: undefined symbol: b_util:
// a.c

void b_util(void);

void a(void) {
    b_util();
}

// b.c

#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void assert_dl(void *p, char *fn_name) {
    if (!p) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", fn_name, dlerror());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void b(void) {
    void *dll = dlopen("./a.so", RTLD_NOW);
    assert_dl(dll, "dlopen");

    void (*a)(void) = dlsym(dll, "a");
    assert_dl(a, "dlsym");

    a();
}

void b_util(void) {
    printf("b_util\n");
}

// c.c

#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void assert_dl(void *p, char *fn_name) {
    if (!p) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", fn_name, dlerror());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    void *dll = dlopen("./b.so", RTLD_NOW);
    assert_dl(dll, "dlopen");

    void (*b)(void) = dlsym(dll, "b");
    assert_dl(b, "dlsym");

    b();
}


Compiler flags are compiler-specific.  Shared library formats and capabilities depend on the operating environment, and in some cases there may be multiple alternatives.  Many shared library systems do allow shared libraries to access variables and functions provided by others linked into the same dynamic executable, including the one that loaded it in the event of dlopen() or similar, but details vary.  Please tell us more about your particular environment.

Have you tried any of the optgions for the dlopen call? Like perhaps RTLD_LAZY? Perhaps in combination with the RTLD_GLOBAL flag?

@JohnBollinger I've tried both clang (Ubuntu clang version 12.0.1-19ubuntu3) and gcc (gcc (Ubuntu 10.5.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 10.5.0) on my Ubuntu 22.04 computer

@Someprogrammerdude Using RTLD_LAZY in both b.c and c.c prints ./c.out: symbol lookup error: ./a.so: undefined symbol: b_util (even when trying it with gcc, clang, and -rdynamic)

@Someprogrammerdude Thank you for the RTLD_GLOBAL edit to your comment, that worked! I just needed to change dlopen("./b.so", RTLD_NOW) to dlopen("./b.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL). :)

As a start: You missed a -ldl from the compilation of c.c

As a side note,  void b_util(void); should be in b.h, included from a.c or a.h as well as from b.c

Some programmer dude in the comments made me aware of the RTLD_GLOBAL flag, and I indeed only needed to change dlopen("./b.so", RTLD_NOW) to dlopen("./b.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL).
A little later I figured out that there is no need for b.so to open a.so. c.c can just open b.so with RTLD_GLOBAL, making b_util visible as if it had been linked directly into the program. After this, dlopen("./a.so", RTLD_NOW) succeeds:
// a.c

void b_util(void);

void a(void) {
    b_util();
}

// b.c

#include <stdio.h>

void b_util(void) {
    printf("b_util\n");
}

// c.c

#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void assert_dl(void *p, char *fn_name) {
    if (!p) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", fn_name, dlerror());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    // Comment dlopen("./b.so") out to cause `undefined symbol: b_util`
    void *dll_b = dlopen("./b.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    assert_dl(dll_b, "dlopen");

    void *dll_a = dlopen("./a.so", RTLD_NOW);
    assert_dl(dll_a, "dlopen");

    void (*a)(void) = dlsym(dll_a, "a");
    assert_dl(a, "dlsym");

    a();
}

